# Terminology of two different tabular representations of aggregated data

Tags: terminology, pivot-table

think of a group of people aged from 21 to 35 years.

Then we can show the number of persons regarding gender and age groups 21-25, 26-30 and 31-35 in (at least) two different ways:

**Type A**

[image]

**Type B**

[image]

What I am curious about is **what names are used to refer to those different types of table structures**?

The practical relevance is that Excel can use Type A as a source for Pivot Tables but not Type B. Often though huge tables of type B are provided for statistics and I would like to google for 'How to turn Type B tables into Type A tables?'.

---

**Terminology (summarized from answers)**:

1. Type A:

   - **R**: 'long data format'
   - '(melted) cross tab
   - **Excel**: 'flat(tened) data table'
2. Type B:

   - **R**: 'wide data format'
   - (traditional) cross tab

The search phrase for Excel/Pivot table would be 'how to flatten a cross table'.

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure there is a universally accepted terminology.  At my work we call the first form a "melted cross tab", and the second form a "traditional cross tab".  In the world of R and the reshape or reshape2 package they are called "long" and "wide" data formats - see eg  [this on R-bloggers.](http://www.r-bloggers.com/reshape-package-in-r-long-data-format-to-wide-back-to-long-again/)

And by the way if you are interested in converting one to another, I thoroughly recommend the `melt()` and `acast()` or `dcast()` functions in that R reshape2 environment.

Comment: this is very interesting and valuable information, thanks!

Comment: @Яaffael1984, I can add to Peter's an alternative terminology. Type B is a 2-way crosstable. Type A is  a 1-way table with nesting (age nested in gender). Type A is also frequently called "aggregated data" or aggregated type of tabulation. P.S. "Nesting" here is just a form of layout and not be confused with "nested experimental design"

Comment: sounds reasonable! though Type B is also aggregated technically.